# Wordpress, PHP - How can I check whether the single post contains youtube video embedded or not?

Tags: wordpress

So I am trying to have quick boolean check to see if the blog post, which is **`single.php`** contains any **youtube** video embedded, and if it does, then display an video embedded image on the **`home.php`** page.

I thought the best way to approach is by string finder using `php` since all `youtube` video embedded contains HTML that looks like this:

```
inframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/...
```

However, the thing is I have no idea where to start out.. If someone could help me how to start out, that will be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If all the embeded youtube videos are iframes, this should work:

```
<?php $content = get_the_content();
preg_match  ('/<iframe(.+)\"/', $content, $matches);
if ($matches !=""){
$hasiframe = true;}
?>
<?php if ($hasiframe)
{
//do something
} else {
//do something else
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a Blog Category called "with video" and then run a loop with just that cat on the home page?

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2' ); //Assuming "id 2" is the category with videos
```

Comment: hummm.. I personally do not want to create another new category just for that.. thank you very much for the suggestion though!